# Calling .getDescribe() on result of SOQL query

Tags: salesforce, apex-code, soql

If I have an SOQL query as follows, which returns only 1 field.

```
String this_soql = 'SELECT SUM(Revenue_Target__c) revenueTarget FROM DM_Account_Plan__c WHERE Id=: the_Id GROUP BY Id';

SObject r = Database.query(this_soql);
```

Can I then go on to get the 'getDescribe' of that field somehow?
Somthing like this perhaps? (which doesnt work)

```
System.debug(r.getDescribe().isAccessible());
```

Any advice or suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found an answer.

You can call the describe method via the SObject's SObjectType like this:

```
System.debug(r.getSObjectType().getDescribe().isAccessible());
```